# How can I get an indexed array from query result in Kohana 3.2?

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-3.2, kohana-db

How can I get the INDEXED array result?

```
$qry1 = DB::select('name')->from('people')->execute();

$assoc_array = $qry1->as_array();
$object      = $qry1->as_object();

// $indexed_array = [...]
```

Only for learning purposes, thanks.

It's like:

```
$indexed_result[0]; // Name
// $indexed_result[1];
// $indexed_result[2];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to get an array of names like `array(0 => 'John', 1 => 'Sam')`?

You should call `$names = $gry1->as_array(NULL, 'name')`;

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was searching for.

Answer (score 1):

http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/database/results#select-asobject-and-asassoc

> The method as_assoc() will remove the object name and return the
>   results set back to an associative array. Since this is the default,
>   this method is seldom required.

So just do your execution.

But if you want only one row take a look at the `current()` method.

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I want... I edited my ask and gave an example. Thanks for the reply :)